# OpenFileDialog opening twice in my C# program

Tags: c#

I am having a problem with a with a code that I used for my C# application. When I click on the browse button and select the file dialogue box opens twice.

```cs
private void txt_location_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string folderPath = "";
    FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        folderPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    }
}

private void Button21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    using(var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog()) {
        DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath)) {
            selectedPath = fbd.SelectedPath;
            txt_location.Text = selectedPath;
        }
    }
}

private void bunifuThinButton21_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    System.IO.StreamWriter file;
    bool isvalid = ValidateInputs();
    try {
        file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(selectedPath + @ "\dred.txt");

        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show("Please, Select valid Path..");
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (isvalid) {
                WriteLines(file);
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex2) {
           MessageBox.Show(ex2.Message);
        } 
        finally {
            file.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, it is only meant to open once to enable me to read the selected file. This works, but only once I have selected the file twice.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That's because when you change the value of `txt_location` in `Button21_Click` the `TextChanged` event from `txt_location` is raised and `txt_location_TextChanged` is called.

Comment: Did you notice that you open a FolderBrowserDialog every time you type something or change the text in the txt_location textbox? When you set the text of this textbox inside the button event your event is called.

Answer (score 0):

You have FolderBrowserDialog being instantiated and shown on two different events:
txt_location_TextChanged
and
Button21_Click

You're having two popups because each one is firing once separately.

You should probably remove the event txt_location_TextChanged entirely unless you need it for another thing that isn't popping the FolderBrowserDialog again.